# Is there a reliable way to automatically detect buttons and confirm codes in emails?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, email, automation

I find the automatic copy-code feature for incoming text messages really nice on my phone and was hoping to implement something similar for my emails. So far I've been able to hook incoming emails into a function and parse them using `node-imap`, but I'm struggling with the actual code autodetection.

For example, some verification codes are 6 numbers/capital letters, like `123X4Y`. Some are a bit shorter and some are much longer, so I arbitrarily wrote the regex `\b[0-9A-Z]{5,12}\b` (I start it at 5 because many emails have a copyright date at the bottom that is 4 numbers). This works decently well but doesn't capture all codes and occasionally captures irrelevant information.

Moreover, many times instead of a code the email just contains a big ol' "Confirm" or "Verify" button. In these cases I'm currently just looking for links with the words confirm or verify either in the link text or the `href`, but this also fails much of the time.

I was wondering if there was any way to more reliably capture action buttons and confirmation codes from emails!

Comment: There is no reliable way to do this. Especially not with regex. However, a Bayesian filter might be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a reliable way to detect buttons in emails without some sort of computer vision as they can take infinitely many forms (a filled in table cell with an anchor, a styled anchor, etc).

You can get the confirmation code with a little bit of NLP -- you could either take a naive approach and just look for keywords like "confirm" or "verify," or you could utilize an NER (Named Entity Recognition) model to identify confirmation codes in an email.

An alternative to NER, you could simply run a Naive Bayes classifier on an encoded vector of the subject line to identify whether or not the email contains a confirmation code. If you are able to identify that the email is a "confirmation" email, you can plug in your regex above and parse out the code.